# Is there any way to get an id element of an item inside a window?

Tags: windows, winapi, command-line

Is there any way to get an id element of an element inside a window (NOT a website)?

What I want to be able to do is to identify a particular button or other element (like a check button or radio button) inside any window, so when a window pops up my program will be able to find and locate that particular button inside it.

For example, libreoffice writer opens, and my program can find the 'New...' button inside it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm confused by what sort of item and window you're talking about, given that you've tagged this "windows" as well as "command-line". Could you maybe give an example?

Comment: I also am confused.  Perhaps you're thinking of UI automation?

Comment: Sorry, I admit it is a very badly phrased question. I'll give it another go and tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Standard window and the "elements" are normal child windows, you can enumerate them easily with the GetWindow function (first use GW_CHILD, than GW_HWNDNEXT).
If you have the handle you can use the GetDlgCtrlID to retrieve the Id.

If the program don't assign the IDs at runtime (some of my program do this), you can use the Id to retrieve the handle.

Comment: Just keep in mind that not all apps/frameworks use Dialog Control IDs at all, so `GetDlgCtrlID()` and `GetDlgItem...()` do not always work.

Comment: Cheers! will give it a go